# jQuery & AJAX, Origin: not matching

Tags: ajax, linux, apache, jquery

if I ask for my jQuery AJAX request Linux Apache Server everything seems OK. If I am requesting Windows XAMPP server, in some browsers on windows it says:

```
"Cross-origin resource sharing check [response verification]
Access denied, Origin: not matching."
```

I think that headers of both server responds are totally same, so i dont know where is the problem.

There are headers of request and respond from Linux server:

Request:

```
URL:http://data.chlupac.com/livetime24/index.php/livetime/get_table/livetiming1/0/0?_=1372192293003
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200 OK
    Request Headersview source
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,cs;q=0.6
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Type:text/plain
    Host:data.chlupac.com
    Referer:http://data.chlupac.com/livetime24/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
    Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
    _:1372192293003
```

Response:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Accept
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:data.chlupac.com
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Length:2508
    Content-Type:text/html
    Date:Tue, 25 Jun 2013 20:31:31 GMT
    Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=99
    Server:Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
    Vary:Accept-Encoding
    X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14
```

That works fine.

And There are my request and respond from windows server:

Request:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,cs;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/plain
Host:championchip.cz
Referer:http://championchip.cz/new/livetime24/livetime/index/livetiming2
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://championchip.cz
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 25 Jun 2013 20:36:27 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=96
Server:Apache/2.2.9 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8h mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.6
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.6
```

I tried it without "http://" before host in Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but it did't work.

There is Javascript, which i am using:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        });
        $.support.cors = true;
        val_livetime="0";
        val_vysledky="0";
        val_kategorie="0";
               $("#vysledky").change(function () {
                val_kategorie="0";
                $("#vysledky option:selected").each(function () {
                    val_vysledky = $(this).val();
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?= site_url('livetime/get_options_kat') ?>/" + val_livetime +"/"+val_vysledky, 
                    contentType: 'text/plain',
                    cache: false}).done(function(html){
                    $("#kategorie").html(html);
                });
                })
                .trigger('change');
```

Thanks for answers. :)

Comment: I would advise to use relative path in AJAX call, so that you won't have anything to match.

Comment: :) That works, for me, but it is not the best way to solve it, because I use the codeigniter REQUEST_URI adress structute, so the sctipt canť find the function.